# Stewart's "Galois Theory"

Tags: galois-theory

One of the questions in Stewart's "Galois Theory" says:

Let $p(t) \in \mathbb{Q}[t]$. Show that $p(t)$ has a unique expression of the form:

$p(t)=(t-\alpha_1)\cdot \cdot \cdot (t- \alpha_r)q(t)$

(except for reordering the $\alpha_j$) where $\alpha_j \in \mathbb{Q}$ for $1 \leq j \leq r$ and $q(t)$ has no zeros in $\mathbb{Q}[t]$.

My question:

But take $p(t)=t^2+1$. $p(t) \in \mathbb{Q}[t]$ clearly, and the (unique) factorization of $p(t)$ is: $p(t)= (t-i)(t+i)$. But then, since this factorization is unique, a representation of the form mentioned in the question is not possible unless we allow $r=0$, which the question clearly doesn't.

Another way to say it: The question seems to imply that if $p(t) \in \mathbb{Q}[t]$, then $\exists$ $\alpha_1 \in \mathbb{Q}$ such that $p(\alpha_1)=0$, which is clearly not the case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your example the roots aren't rational, but the $\alpha_j$ are supposed to belong to $\mathbb{Q}$. Hence the unique expression for your $p(t)$ is $p(t) = q(t) = t^2 + 1$, because $p(t)$ already has no zeroes in $\mathbb{Q}[t]$. There is no reason to exclude the case $r = 0$.

Comment: Ok. The question states $1 \leq j \leq r$, which sort of implies $r \geq 1$. That was my confusion.

Comment: @M10687 This is common mathematical "abuse of language", if you will. You should read the question as some variant of "Show that there exists an integer $r \geq 0$ such that $p(t)$ has a unique expression of the form..." Then the part $1 \leq j \leq r$ makes sense even if $r = 0$, because then there are no such $j$.

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks!